# Trying to validate jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, user-interface, datepicker

I am trying to check if a date is older than today's date & show an error if true. What is currently happening is if the month is less than today's month, the error is showing even if the year is set to 2014 or beyond. For example today is 4/18/2013 which doesn't have an error, but 4/17/2014 & 3/17/2014 get errors but 5/17/2013 does not. It seems the year is being ignored during the check. Hope that made a little sense...

```
    $("#expDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: 0,
        onClose: function(selectedDate) {
            var currDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date());
            if (selectedDate < currDate) {              
                $("#warning").append("The number has expired"); 
            } else {
                $("#warning").html(""); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly with maxDate option

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date() });
```

Comment: Thanks RafH, but when I add that, it limits the date picker to only today's date. I need to be able to have all future dates available. I'm trying to to show an error on a past due date.

Comment: You just need to set the minDate option aswell, for example minDate:new Date(1900, 6, 2). It will allow you to pick a date between 06-02-1900 and today

Comment: That works just the opposite of how I need it. That lets me pick all days in the past, and it gives an error, but it doesn't allow for any future dates, which is what I need. 
The field is for a date that has an expiration. When a user logs in, I need to show that the date has expired or is in the past if they type it in manually.

Comment: My bad, just do $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate:newDate(), maxDate: '+1y'}); It will let you pick a date betwwen now and now + 1 year. You can find how to adjust the maxDate option here : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate